# Why does eye(size(X)) (where X is some array) throw an error?

Tags: methods, julia

Why can I use

```
X = randn(size(Y));
```

and

```
X = eye(size(Y,1), size(Y,2));
```

but not

```
X = eye(size(Y));
```

? It throws the following error, which I don't really understand:

> ERROR: `eye` has no method matching `eye(::(Int64,Int64))`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error

> ERROR: `eye` has no method matching `eye(::(Int64,Int64))`

should tip you off on the nature of the problem. When in doubt, have a look at the function's methods and check whether the types align with any of them.

## `eye` methods

You can list the methods provided for `eye` by calling `methods` on it:

```
julia> methods(eye)
# 7 methods for generic function "eye":
eye{T}(::Type{Diagonal{T}},n::Int64) at linalg/diagonal.jl:92
eye(T::Type{T<:Top},m::Integer,n::Integer) at array.jl:176
eye(m::Integer,n::Integer) at array.jl:182
eye(T::Type{T<:Top},n::Integer) at array.jl:183
eye(n::Integer) at array.jl:184
eye(S::SparseMatrixCSC{Tv,Ti<:Integer}) at sparse/sparsematrix.jl:413
eye{T}(x::AbstractArray{T,2}) at array.jl:185
```

## Do types align?

First, let's generate some random data:

```
julia> Y=rand(3,3)
3x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 0.323068  0.759352   0.684859
 0.357021  0.0706659  0.78324 
 0.128993  0.763624   0.458284
```

So, why does `eye(size(Y,1), size(Y,2))` work? Because both `size(Y,1)` and `size(Y,2)` are of type `Int64`,

```
julia> typeof(size(Y,1))
Int64

julia> typeof(size(Y,2))
Int64
```

which is a subtype of `Integer`,

```
julia> Int64 <: Integer
true
```

and `eye` provides a method that expects two arguments of type `Integer`:

```
eye(m::Integer,n::Integer)
```

And why does't `eye(size(Y))` work? Because `size` returns a pair,

```
julia> typeof(size(Y))
(Int64,Int64)
```

and `eye` provides no method that takes a pair as argument.

## Relation to currying

What you would need is a function `f` such that

```
f(eye)(size(Y))
```

would be equivalent to

```
eye(size(Y,1), size(Y,2))
```

You could say that `f` would [*uncurry*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) `eye`. Unfortunately for you, the Julia devs have [no plans to introduce such a function](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/554).

## Solution

Anyway, you're overcomplicating things. There is no need to use `size`, here; simply applying `eye` to array `Y` produces the desired result:

```
julia> eye(Y)
3x3 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  0.0  0.0
 0.0  1.0  0.0
 0.0  0.0  1.0
```

Comment: Raises the question of whether this was intended or simply an oversight, though, and whether we should expect both `fn(a,b,c)` and `fn((a,b,c))` to work with `eye` as well.

Comment: @DSM I don't think it's an oversight. Using `size` is actually unnecessary, here; `eye(Y)` does the right thing.